# How can I read in a column from a text file as a new column in an existing dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 226 .txt files of sequencing data with two columns each, 'Gene' and 'sample ID'.  'Gene' contains 58524 gene names and 'sample ID' contains the sample ID as the header and expression value for each gene.  I'd like to generate a dataframe with 'Gene' and one column containing values for each of my 226 files, each of which is a unique sample. 'Gene' in all files is in the same order.

I've tried this and a few versions of this

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".*.txt")
df <- filelist %>%
 set_names(.) %>%
 map_df(read_table2, .id = "FileName")
```

When I run this code, df contains 226 columns and 13,226,424 entries.  Each text file generates it's own column, but does not fill in the existing rows.  Rather, the whole list of genes is added again at the bottom, and the next column begins to fill in.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsOXQ.png) is what df looks like at the transition from column1 to column 2.  I want each new text file to create a column that fills in the existing rows, so that df would contain 226 columns with 58524 entries.
Here is an example of the txt files

Gene    CTRL147R

5S  3.6387

5   0.01

7SK 0.01

A1BG-AS1    1.2498

Comment: Can you post an example of the format of the .txt files?

Comment: @AkindeleDavies yes, I have updated the post

Comment: Sorry, could you also give an example of what the output dataframe should look like for the example input file?

Comment: So what happens when you run your current code `df <- filelist %>% set_names(.) %>% map_df(read_table2, .id = "FileName")` ? What does `df` contains vs what would you like to have?